Postgres count function returns wrong value when using FDW
My following query returns a single average_donation_usd value
WITH                                                                                       
        ts AS ( SELECT * FROM transactions_fwd WHERE org_id = 1 ),
        rp AS ( SELECT * FROM recurring_payments_fwd WHERE org_id = 1 )
SELECT AVG(t.usd_amount_cents / 100) AS average_donation_usd
FROM ts t 
JOIN rp r ON r.id = t.recurring_payment_id
WHERE t.status = 'paid' AND t.deleted_at IS NULL AND t.amount_refunded_cents = 0

But when I wrap it to select count(*) from (my_query) i get 288 as a result, but I expect it to be 1.
select count(*)
FROM (
WITH                                                                                       
        transactions AS ( SELECT * FROM transactions_fwd WHERE org_id = 1 ),
        recurring_payments AS ( SELECT * FROM recurring_payments_fwd WHERE org_id = 1 )
SELECT AVG(t.usd_amount_cents / 100) AS average_donation_usd
FROM transactions t 
JOIN recurring_payments r ON r.id = t.recurring_payment_id
WHERE t.status = 'paid' AND t.deleted_at IS NULL AND t.amount_refunded_cents = 0
);

I tried to create materialized views to see it this bug relates to using FWD tables.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW transactions AS
SELECT * FROM transactions_fwd WHERE org_id = 1;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW recurring_payments AS
SELECT * FROM recurring_payments_fwd WHERE org_id = 1;

And it worked well returning me 1 as a result.
select count(*)
FROM (
WITH                                                                                       
        transactions AS ( SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE org_id = 1 ),
        recurring_payments AS ( SELECT * FROM recurring_payments WHERE org_id = 1 )
SELECT AVG(t.usd_amount_cents / 100) AS average_donation_usd
FROM transactions t 
JOIN recurring_payments r ON r.id = t.recurring_payment_id
WHERE t.status = 'paid' AND t.deleted_at IS NULL AND t.amount_refunded_cents = 0
);


My OS and Postgres version (hosted on heroku)
User => select version();
                                                              version                                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 16.4 (Ubuntu 16.4-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)


Can you please produce a minimal reproducible example. That would include table definitions and some data to show the problem. Also, it is odd that you define materialized views, but the query after that still includes the same names as CTEs, so the materialized views are likely not used at all. Also, you take an avg of a column in one table, and the join with another table will likely not change the result (it will multiply the sum by multiplying rows, but then divide again, unless the right table is empty).
